# Getting bulk update to work in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.6

My app is being made in laravel 5.6

**Situation:**
I have a table called "members" with a column called "membershipstatus_id".
options for status are 4, 5 and 1
4 = Active, 5 = pending and 1= expired

**Target:**
I want to update all active(4) members to pending(5) and all pending ones to expire(1).

**Solutions I have tried:**
So far, below is what i have tried with no result.

```
    // get all active and pending members        
    $members = Member::where('membershipstatus_id', 5)
                ->orWhere('membershipstatus_id', 4)
                ->get();


    // bulk update with chunk of 200, if this is possible
    $members->chunk(200, function($members)
    {


        foreach($members as $member)
        {

            // if status is pending, update to expire
            if($member->membershipstatus_id == 5)
            {
              $member->update(['membershipstatus_id' => 1]);
             }
            // if status is active, update to pending, i updated a small mistake here. 
            if($member->membershipstatus_id == 5)
            {
              $member->update(['membershipstatus_id' => 4]);
             }


        }
    }
 );

return "update confirm";
```

Now, If anyone has a cleaner and swift way to do this, Please let me know, also, Im sure i have made some stupid mistake up there. Please point me to the right direction.

Ashish

Comment: Do you want to just have a button in front-end so when you click changes happening or you want ability of selecting user then click on button and changes happen?

Comment: Yes @mafortis , you are exactly right.

Comment: about which one? need select option or just simple button?

Comment: I think you give wrong condition and value at your second `if` in your `foreach`

Comment: should be `if ($member->membershipstatus_id == 4)
            {
              $member->update(['membershipstatus_id' => 5]);
             }`, I guess

Comment: my bad, there was small mistake in question. editing this right now

Comment: @DharmaSaputra Yes, i fixed that. I made this error while i was typing the question. Application has same code as you are suggesting.

Comment: @mafortis just a button that super admin presses to bulk update without selecting users, code will affect all available users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the query builder like:

```
// update pending to expired
DB::table('members')
    ->where('membershipstatus_id', 5)
    ->update(['membershipstatus_id' => 1]);

// update active to pending
DB::table('members')
    ->where('membershipstatus_id', 4)
    ->update(['membershipstatus_id' => 5]);
```

Comment: is it possible to do something like below

        Member::where('membershipstatus_id', 5)
               ->update(['membershipstatus_id' => 1]);

Comment: Thanks mate, Solved using Member instead of DB